# How do you install jQuery in Wordpress?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

How can I install jQuery on my Wordpress site?

Comment: You don't install jquery, you merely include the library and start using it.

Comment: did you try to search for an answer?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery and Wordpress](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/788071/jquery-and-wordpress)

Comment: @Blender. I want to add some effects on my site using jQuery.

Comment: Just a note. WP already uses jQuery so you just need to put `wp_enqueue_script("jquery"); ` in your `<head>`

Answer (score 9):

Though one of the Answer is already Accepted but I feel the following technique may help somebody.

Include the following code at `Plugin Page` OR at `function.php`

```
function include_jQuery() {
    if (!is_admin()) {
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    }
}
add_action('init', 'include_jQuery');
```

Definitely you can use any meaningful function name instead off `include_jQuery`.

Alternately, you can use the following code:

```
function include_jQuery() {
    if (!is_admin()) {
        // comment out the next two lines to load the local copy of jQuery
        wp_deregister_script('jquery'); 
        wp_register_script('jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js', false, '1.8.3'); 
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    }
}
add_action('init', 'include_jQuery');
```

Finally, as a general rule, you should not use the `$` variable for `jQuery` unless you have used one of the [shortcuts](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries#Referencing_Magic_-_Shortcuts_for_jQuery). The following is an example of how to shortcut jQuery to safely use the `$` variable:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    /* You can safely use $ in this code block to reference jQuery */
});
```

You may like [THIS](http://www.ericmmartin.com/5-tips-for-using-jquery-with-wordpress/) link as well from where I personally learn the above technique(s). A Very BIG Thanks to **Ericm Martin!**

Answer (score 1):

Jquery Already packaged with the Wordpress installation, and gets available with it.
Check the source code when you get your new Wordpress Blog installed.