# How to make jQuery load as a first script in header in WordPress?

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress, header

my website and plugins insert some jquery code between `HTML` tag and also putting a jquery dependent plugin as a first script tag so whatever I do to insert jquery as a first script in the head section I can't make it  work

I tried

```
function use_jquery_from_google () {
    if (is_admin()) {
        return;
    }

    global $wp_scripts;
    if (isset($wp_scripts->registered['jquery']->ver)) {
        $ver = $wp_scripts->registered['jquery']->ver;
    } else {
        $ver = '3.1.4';
    }

    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_register_script('jquery', "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/$ver/jquery.min.js", false, $ver);
}
```

also putting JQuery CND script tag

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

almost everywhere including directly into `header.php` and `index.php` of the theme
when I put the script tag before `wp_head()` and load the page there are still 15 more script tag before it and I think they are related to my plugins

so what can I do to make Jquery load really before everything because editing third party plugins is really frustrating and time-consuming

**UPDATE**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Cameron,  you can use jQuery by enqueueing it in your header.php or functions.php file.  Here are a few articles with the step by step:

https://digwp.com/2009/06/including-jquery-in-wordpress-the-right-way/

or

[How do you install jQuery in Wordpress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5775512/how-do-you-install-jquery-in-wordpress)

**Updated:**

Try changing your `<head>` section of your header.php file to this:

```
<head>
<?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery"); ?>
<meta charset="<php bloginfo('charset'); ?>" />
<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
```

Comment: as I said I did this , but the problem is one of my plugins put a jqeury dependent script file on top of everything

Comment: Cameron, I don't see this in the code you provided.  Try putting this at the very top of your header.php: `<?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery"); ?>`

Comment: before wp_head() ?

Comment: Cameron, yes, based on the article I linked

Comment: I did but still more script tags before it , I think my plugins put these scripts before everything, I want to override it

Comment: hmm, are you still deregistering the default jQuery script as noted in the code you provided?

Comment: no , I commented everything, Im updating my code, please check

Comment: if I put <?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery"); ?> into header before wp_head() the result is still the same

Comment: Cameron, is the updated code I put in my answer how you had it set up?

Comment: you put it before meta tag ? should it make a difference ? I think you didnt get the problem ,  as I told you
There are plugins which put more scripts before this one 
I doesnt matter where I put the code in the header. php 
I should do something my script tag load before them

How do I override ?

Comment: Cameron, I am sorry I wasn't able to provide you with a solution that resolved the other scripts from loading.  I was answering this "so what can I do to make Jquery load really before everything because editing third party plugins is really frustrating and time-consuming"